# SharePoint 2010-move central admin site

Tags: service-application

We will planning to move central admin site from app server-1 to app server -2.

my Query : **any know issues or possible impact due to change the CA host from server to another.**

can we run config wizrd wfe1 and wfe2  ???(As we know, must to run : app1( for remove ca host) and app2(for map CA host))

Many thanks
P.Mohan.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run into any issues. Order doesn't matter, you should be able to also first install CA on APP2 and then remove it from APP1. I personally would maybe first install it to APP2, so just in case there are any problems, you can continue using CA on APP1 while solving issues on APP2.

Depending on how you access the CA, you might need to make some changes in load balancer to redirect CA traffic to APP2. But if you're accessing CA using server name, or otherwise not going through LB to CA you don't need to do anything.

Yo do not need to run Config Wizard on WFE servers, only on the servers from/to you are moving the CA.

Comment: Thanks lot.In my case not wfe servers.we are planning to move CA host from Application Server-1(current CA host server) to Application Server-2

Comment: Updated my answer, please let me know if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this article and didn't have any issues: [How to change Central Admin Host in SharePoint 2010](http://kirkbarrett.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/how-to-change-central-admin-host-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Basically you remove Central Admin from Server 1 using **SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard**. When finished, you add Central Admin from Server 2 using the same **SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard**. Be sure to use the Wizard from the server you're effecting.

To prevent lots of tears and heartache though, do a farmbackup just in case :-)